# Unity sometimes the facing camera position node doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

Unity version: 2021.3.6f1
URP and using visual effect graph

I made a very simple demo to show the problem

without facing camera turned on
[image: without facing camera turned on]

AND with the facing camera position node turned on
[image: AND with the facing camera position node turned on]

And it's not because the viewport virtual camera angle thing. The virtual camera in the viewport is very close to the actual scene camera. And it should face to the virtual camera anyway.

The link to the actual visual effect graph I used.
[download link](https://las.zeddal.com/vfxstrip.zip)
It's a zip file of the actual .unitypackage file

Is it a bug or am I missing something? How do I fix the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

apparently I used the wrong trigger...
it should be trigger over time, not trigger always.

so...case closed.